# not able to import classes from jar which was downloaded from custom maven nexus repository

Tags: java, maven, jar, repository, nexus

I have deployed my external jar to local Nexus repository. I have defined repository in setting.xml and provided dependency in POM.xml.

My project is able to download the jar in Maven dependencies , however When I tried to import any class from the that jar.

I am not able to import it. It is saying `cannot be resolved to a type`.

So in short I am not able to use the classes from jar which i have downloaded from local nexus repository.

Can any one help me here?

here is repository part of my Setting.xml file

```
  <profiles>
     <profile>
   <id>myprofile</id>
 <repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>modelhelper-repo</id>
     <name>Modelhelper repository</name>
     <url>http://localhost:8081/#browse/browse:maven-public </url>
   </repository>
 </repositories>     
</profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
```

myprofile

here is dependency from pom.xml file:

```
       <dependency>   
       <groupId>com.ravina</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelhelper</artifactId> 
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

There is Employee and other many classes in this `modelhelper-1.0.0.jar`, which I am not able to import in my project.

Comment: Build your project with `clean install` and show us the errors.

Comment: and show `jar tvf ` on your jar file.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen My JAr is not valid jar. Maven Nexus Manager is download html file with .jar location

Comment: @JFMeier it build success with no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repository's URL in *settings.xml* doesn't seem to be correct - it looks like you've used the URL from your browser. The URL you should use is *http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-public/*

The repository URL can be found in *Administration -> Repositories -> [repository_name]*

Comment: Here the problem is not with Download. Problem is in Jar File, however thanks for your response.

Comment: Hey  @Dawid My problem has been solved now. I was using URL from browser, so It was downloading invalid jar (with html content). Now I am using correct URL as mentioned by you and yes it is downloading correct Jar. Thank you :) .

Comment: Hi @dawid-sawa, you were spot on! Thank you so much! I had the same issue and it also solved my problem!

Answer (score -1):

Scope of the dependency is provided (means will be provided by container/parent). If you want to use the dependency during compile time. Change the scope to compile.

Comment: That is not true. Provided Dependencies are on the compile classpath.